# Javascript replace parts of string to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I wish to do a search and replace in a string. It searches for any word that begins with "$" and replaces it with a value from an array. For example if the string is:

```
[div class='news'][h4]$title[/h4][p]$desc[/p][/div]
```

It replaces [] to <> (already done). But then i want it to replace $title with data from an array. So data["title"] and then $desc would be replaced with data["desc"].
The code i have so far is

```
var obj = $('#'+id);
var url = $(obj).attr('loadJSON');
var format = $(obj).attr('responseFormat');
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var html = "";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var tmp = format;
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\[+(.*?)\]+/g,"<$1>");
        tmp = tmp.replace();
    }
});
```

The format is the string which it will replace in, and data (from the JSON response) is the array which i want the variables to change to.

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

then add as last replacement

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/\$([a-z]+)/gi, function(match, v) {
   return data[v] || v;
})
```

note that in case of `data[v]` is undefined you could return something else like `data[v] || ["not found", v].join(' ')` just to track what variable is missing

Comment: as aside suggestion you could use *{$var}* instead, since is a wider used sytntax in microtemplating

Comment: I would do, but the html files are generated from PHP first, using a template system, which already uses {$var} so i had to use something slightly different. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

I'm no JS expert, but this looks wrong in so many ways... your data object should be a JS object, that is something like `{ title: 'Generic title.', description: 'It's a generic title' }`.

Why not put the values into paragraph elements, and then insert those into the div (i.e., you append them). Something like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $('div.news').append($('<p />').text(data.title));
    $('div.news').append($('<p />').txt(data.description));
});
```

Comment: The data object is a JS object, its loaded via AJAX from an external source, and i wanted this in a function which could be easily intergrated to format external content in any conatainer. So for example, i could use the same JS function to load data and insert it into a table

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
tmp = tmp.replace(/\$([a-z]+)/gi, function(match) {
    match = match.replace('$', '');
   return (data[match] || match)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uZbk8/

Comment: if you're using a capturing group, you may just pass another parameter to the callback and avoid an inner replacement

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes i saw (and upvoted) your answer, it's much better! :)